# Jersey Produce response RSS Feed (MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/rss+xml)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

I am writing a List of Blog response for my RESTtFull webapplication with Jersey. How can I produce RSS feed with jersey? I have tried with

```
@GET
@Produces("application/rss+xml")
public Response list() {
    Map<Object, Object> apiResponse     = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    Map<Object, Object> serviceResponse = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    try {
        List<Blog> blogs = blogService.list();
        serviceResponse.put("total", blogs.size());
        serviceResponse.put("list", blogs); 
        apiResponse.put("apiresponse", serviceResponse);

        return Response.ok(apiResponse).build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in getting blog list:", e);
        apiResponse.put("error", e.getMessage());
    }

    return Response.status(500).entity(apiResponse).build();
}
```

This is the blog list method in my service layer:

```
public List<Blog> list() throws Exception {

        List<Blog> blogs= new ArrayList<Blog>();
        Query query = new Query();

        blogs= SpringDataDBUtils.getMongoOperations().find(query, Blog.class);

        return blogs;
    }
```

But it does not work. It produces the error:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/rss+xml, type=class java.util.HashMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Jersey doesn't mention it can handle conversion of `HashMap` to an XML representation.

> XML media types (text/xml, application/xml and application/...+xml)
>
> - javax.xml.transform.Source
> - javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
> - Application supplied JAXB classes (types annotated with @XmlRootElement or @XmlType)

Even if the other objects you use in the hashmap are annotated to be converted to XML, it won't work.

I suggest you creating a dedicated representation object, for example a `BlogListResponse`, which is annotated with `@XmlXXX` annotations, same goes for the `Blog` entities you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

As mention [by @Frederik Heremans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42113470/2587435), the problem is with the `(Hash)Map`. But even if you get the Map to work, you're still not even going to have a valid RSS format. You're just going to have random XML, which is impossible for RSS readers to read.

If you want real RSS format, you should check out the [RSS Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS). There you'll see the the different RSS versions and formats. After that, you should find a dedicated library that handles RSS feeds correctly. Personally I would suggest [Rome](https://rometools.github.io/rome/index.html). I think it's the most popular Java library out there. (Make sure to check out the link. There are a lot of examples).

The Rome library has a single root interface `SyndFeed` that models the RSS feeds (it supports multiple RSS versions). With that `SyndFeed` you can create a [JAX-RS Provider](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html) that handles the (de)serialization. Here is a complete working example

```
import com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.rometools.rome.io.FeedException;
import com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedOutput;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

/**
 * Example JAX-RS provider for Rome {@code SyndFeed}.
 */
@Provider
@Produces("application/rss+xml")
@Consumes("application/rss+xml")
public class SyndFeedProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<SyndFeed>, MessageBodyReader<SyndFeed> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                               Annotation[] annotations,MediaType mediaType) {
        return SyndFeed.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(SyndFeed syndFeed, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(SyndFeed syndFeed, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String,
                        Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        SyndFeedOutput output = new SyndFeedOutput();
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream);
        try {
            output.output(syndFeed, writer);
        } catch (FeedException e) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                              Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return SyndFeed.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public SyndFeed readFrom(Class<SyndFeed> type, Type genericType,
                             Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
                             MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
                             InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream);
        SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();

        try {
            return input.build(reader);
        } catch (FeedException e) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to register this provider with your Jersey application, either implicitly through package scanning, or explicitly with the `ResourceConfig`.

This provider handles both serializing and de-serializing the `SyndFeed`. So in your resources, you can create `SyndFeed` instances and just return that as the response entity. The provider will handle the serialization. The example provider also handler de-serialization from it's serialized form back into a `SyndFeed` class, in case you want to use it on the client, maybe for testing.

You can find a complete working test case in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/1e56337e297f129634a613f54c0cc6e0)